# LINQ to SQL complex query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following object

```
public Cell {
    public string CategoryId {get; set;}
    public DateTime FromTime {get; set}
    public DateTime ToTime {get; set}
}
```

I have a DB table that is called Item that looks like this:

```
Item

-------------------------
CategoryId    LastUpdated
```

Now in the code I have a list of Cell `List<Cell> ToBeFetchedFromDB` that contains more than one Cell, suppose the list contains `Foo` and `Bar`, I want to dynamically build a query like this `BY INTERATING THROUGH THE COLLECTION ToBeFetchedFromDB WITHIN MY LINQ TO SQL QUERY` instead of statically constructing the query:

```
from x in Item
where x.CategoryId == Foo.CategoryId && Foo.FromTime < x.LastUpdated < Foo.ToTime
      || x.CategoryId == Bar.CategoryId && Bar.FromTime < x.LastUpdated < Bar.ToTime
select x
```

I have been trying but can't figure it out :(

Thanks guys!

Comment: How doesn't your code work?

Comment: As @Keith said, I want to dynamically iterate through the List(), not just list them out statically.

Comment: And I don't understand the downvotes ... It's a legitimate question ...

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do, and you also seem to be asking people to just hand you the code. I've read your question three times and I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the "not-so-well-phrased" question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) you can go through each item in your list using a `foreach` and add a new option for your filter:

```
var filter = PredicateBuilder.False<Item>();

foreach (var cell in ToBeFetchedFromDB)
{
    filter = PredicateBuilder.Or(filter, item => 
        item.CategoryId == cell.CategoryId &&
        cell.FromTime < item.LastUpdated &&
        item.LastUpdated < cell.ToTime);
}

var query = Item.Where(filter);
```

A copy of `PredicateBuilder` from the link:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just wondering, shouldn't the predicate be true?

Comment: @Noobie Nope.  Anything ORed with true is true.  If you stared with true you'd never end up with false.  If you were ANDing each of the expressions together then you'd start with `True`.

Comment: You sir are awesome! I owe you dinner!